# Deploying lightning web component from VScode to sandbox takes more time

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, vs-code, time

I am trying to deploy lightning web component from VScode to the sandbox using the command SFDX:Deploy Source to Org. It was working fine previously but for the past 2 days, deploying is taking more time(even an hour still not deployed).Sometimes it works sometimes taking more time.Has anyone faced this kind of issue and any solution for it?

Comment: what's your CLI version? `sfdx -v`

Comment: I presume you're working in a shared sandbox with other developers?

Comment: Try these: (1) Run `sfdx update` and after the update completes successfully, try deployment. (2) Check if any previous deployment is stuck (in the Deployment Status page under `Setup > Environment > Deploy > Deployment Status`. If yes, cancel this deployment and then try your deployment.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves CLI version is sfdx-cli/7.71.0-4193fb4acc win32-x64 node-v12.18.3

Comment: @sfdcfox, Yes.It is a shared sandbox

Comment: @arut, I ran sfdx update and updated cli to latest version(7.72). In the Deployment status, I could not find any other deployment pending. But still I face this issue.

Comment: Are you facing this problem while deploying to other orgs as well?

Comment: I haven't tried in other orgs.